# I have a react app using Firebase authentication, how to listen for changes when the user verifies his email?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried using these functions, and they are not called when the user verifies his email:

```
- onAuthStateChanged
- onIdTokenChanged
```

I am expecting to use a callback when the user verifies their email, by clicking the link sent to their email

Comment: There are no listeners for when a user's profile changes.  The ones you listed are for sign in, sign out, and ID token changes.  If you want a listener for profile changes, you'll have to implement something yourself, maybe using one of the realtime databases provided by Firebase.